# How to get the child element from event.target.parentElement by id name

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get value of input which id name is "q" when I click the cancel button. I'm just a beginner and no idea how to get it. Thanks for your helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>

    <div>
      Cake
      <div class="delcontainer">
        <button class=" btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="cancel(event)">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div for="">1000</div>
    <div>
      <input type="number" value="3" id="q">
    </div>

    <div class="total">300</div>

  </div>

  <script>
    function cancel(e) {
      console.log(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you use `document.getElementById('q')` ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>

    <div>
      Cake
      <div class="delcontainer">
        <button class=" btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="cancel(event)">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div for="">1000</div>
    <div>
      <input type="number" value="3" id="q">
    </div>

    <div class="total">300</div>

  </div>

  <script>
    function cancel(e) {
      console.log(document.querySelector('#q').value);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Since Id's should be unique on every page you can get it like this else you'd just go and do

```js
    function cancel(e) {
      console.log(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('#q').value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an element with id
you can just use `document.querySelector('#q')`
like below

```js
const valueOfInput = document.querySelector('#q').value;
```